# Which partition should i shrink the volume size to install linux ? Are there are limit of primary partition?

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, partitioning, operating-systems

I am windows user. Now I want a dual boot with linux. A screen shot of my computer's disk management:

[image: disk management screenshot]

Which partition do you recommend I shrink? And if I'm not mistaken, operating system must installed inside primary partition type. What is the limit on primary partitions on one HDD?

Answer (score 1):

Linux can be installed in any partition (primary or logical). Only Windows has some limitations, but maybe the newest windows versions don't have them anymore. I would recommend to shrink the last (D:) partition and create a new one after the last partition.

With a good linux distribution, it is very unlikely that something goes wrong during installation. Regardless, I would strongly recommend to make a backup of your system before installation and before you shrink your partition.

Comment: some windows only allow 4 partitions, so OP might want to move data on D: to C: and install Linux on D:

Comment: Windows can be installed in an extended partition as well, only the boot partition needs to be primary. @BenPlont: Technically that a limitation of the MBR partitioning scheme, not Windows. GPT will allow you to have up to 128 "primary" partitions.

Comment: @Karan, that is true. I thought that since the screenshot shows 4 partitions rather than volumes, OP had MBR rather that GUID.

Comment: Nothing in the screen shot clearly identifies the disk as being MBR or GPT. For that, you need to right-click on "Disk 0" in the screen shot, click "Properties" in the pop-up menu, and select the "Volumes" tab in the resulting dialog box. The "Partition Style" line identifies the partition table type. See [this page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootmode.html#windows) for more details.